# Copy contents from capture group to another subsequent line

Tags: regex

Let’s say I’ve got this text:

```
Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: replace-with-code

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: replace-with-code
```

I want the resulting string to look like:

```
Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1234

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1122
```

I can capture the digits in a group with: `: (\d{4}).`

Yet how would I replace the group’s contents in with the `replace-with-code` part?

Comment: what `regex` engine do you use? I mean, what is the context of your question, what programming language or tool you use to execute your regular expression?

Comment: There is no specific language involved. Assume I have a lot of text like this in VS Code open. And a lot of paragraphs that follow this schema as outlined in the question. I am just wondering if this is possible with vanilla regex. If not, then my next step would be likely to use JavaScript or R to parse the text, create variables and iterate over all instances of `replace-with-code-from-line-1`

Comment: There is not really a think like vanilla regex, and I don't see a pattern in the example strings. But when having 3 lines, something like this could work. Match `(: )(\d{4})(\.\n.*\n.*)` and replace with `$1$2$3$2`

Comment: You are right, I added another line to show my paragraph schema. You attempt is very close indeed. Yet, it is not replacing the `replace-with-code` segment.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use awk - something like:

```
awk '/[0-9]{4}./ {match($0,"([0-9]{4})",n);}{gsub(/replace-with-code/,n[0]); print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Edited to fix bad shell escaping

Comment: Thanks for introducing me into `awk`! Just read some stuff about it... However, I do get an error with your line: `awk: syntax error at source line 1 context is /\d{4}./ >>>  {match($0,"(\d{4})", <<<` Not sure where the syntax error is on this thing...

Comment: my bad - I made a change without testing!  Try the edited version

Comment: I think the `\d` was not the issue, I still get the same error :/ I will try to debug later