# Copy the string that matches a regex to another location using awk

Tags: regex, awk

Assume I have a file `input.txt` with the following contents:

```
Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: replace-with-code

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: replace-with-code
```

I want to create an `output.txt` which looks like this:

```
Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1234

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1122
```

The proposed way from here: [Copy contents from capture group to another subsequent line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698209/copy-contents-from-capture-group-to-another-subsequent-line) :

`awk '/[0-9]{4}./ {match($0,"([0-9]{4})",n);}{gsub(/replace-with-code/,n[0]); print}' inputfile > outputfile`

Returns an error. I am just not able to fix this issue... Any awk magicians can help me here?

Comment: Just to add here, match with capturing group works in GNU `awk` AFAIK IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '{gsub(/replace-with-code/, p)} /[0-9]{4}\.$/ {p = $NF+0} 1' file

Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1234

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1122
```

Comment: Excellent, I turned it into `awk '{gsub(/replace-with-code/, p)} /[0-9]{4}\.$/ {p = $NF+0} 1' input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are not worried about blank lines in between actual data lines then try following GNU `awk` program. Basically its using GNU `awk`'s `match` function in which we could use regex(`(^|\n)([^:]*: )([0-9]+)(\.\n[^\n]+\n[^:]*: )`) and can catch values as per our requirement and while printing them we can print them as per required order.

```bash
awk -v RS= '
match($0,/(^|\n)([^:]*: )([0-9]+)(\.\n[^\n]+\n[^:]*: )/,arr){
  print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[4] arr[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex in above `awk` program.

```
(^|\n)                ##In first capturing group using regex ^|\n
([^:]*: )             ##In next one matching everything till colon space first occurrence.
([0-9]+)              ##In this capturing group matching 1 or more digits.
(\.\n[^\n]+\n[^:]*: ) ##In 4th capturing group matching literal dot followed by new line followed by
                      ##non-new lines followed by new line till very first occurrence of colon followed by space.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would exploit GNU `AWK` paragraph mode for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: replace-with-code

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: replace-with-code
```

then

```
awk BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}{print gensub(/([0-9]+)(.*)replace-with-code/, "\\1\\2\\1", 1)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1234

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1122
```

Explanation: setting `RS` to empty string provokes GNU `AWK` that rows are separated by blank lines rather than newlines. I set `ORS` to preserve such lines. Then for every row I use [`gensub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, to capture number which I simply define as 1 or more digits and what is between said number and `replace-with-code`, last I do not capture as it will be not kept. Then replace with what was captured in desired output. **Disclaimer**: this solution that you never has more than 1 subsequent blank lines.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

skip all the `gensub()/gsub()`, no `match()` needed, no arrays needed, no capture groups needed … and just make it a basic `if-then-else` :

> ```
> echo "${input_data….}" |
>
> mawk 'NF<=!__ || $NF =_=/replace-with-code$/ ? +_ : $NF' FS=': ' OFS=': '
> ```

```
Hello my name is: 1234.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1234

Hello my name is: 1122.
My favorite color is blue.
This was my code from the introduction line: 1122
```